# YouTube API - Direct Upload - 413 Request Entity Too Large

Tags: php, sockets, upload, youtube-api

I've been trying to upload videos to the YouTube API via direct upload. I finally cracked the OAuth Process and I have a valid token. I really only need to do 2 things with YouTube, Authenticate and upload. I am not browsing, or using any of the other functionality. Users upload videos to this website, and I send them to YouTube for playback.

I feel like I've come 80-90% of the way on my own here, so I do not want to scrap this and use the Zend Library that Google provides.

Problem:
When I send the request I get this response:

```
HTTP/1.1 413 Request Entity Too Large
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 171
Date: Thu, 18 Apr 2013 18:33:22 GMT
Expires: Thu, 18 Apr 2013 18:33:22 GMT
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Frame-Options: SAMEORIGIN
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Server: GSE
Connection: close
```

If I turn on the warnings, I also get a Broken Pipe warning, which is probably just the code trying to upload the data through the closed/refused connection.

My request is this:

```
POST /feeds/api/users/default/uploads HTTP/1.1 
Host: gdata.youtube.com Connection: close 
User-Agent: PHP Accept-encoding: identity 
Authorization: Bearer <TOKEN IS HERE> 
GData-Version: 2.0 
X-GData-Key: key=<MYKEYISHERE>
Slug: throwing_can.mp4 
Content-Type: multipart/related; boundary="5170429d1b193" 
Content-Length: 3920610
```

With the file itself chunked and written to the stream.

```
function ytapi_write_file($handle, $path, $chunksize = 8192){
    $filehandle = fopen($path, 'r');
    while(!feof($filehandle)){
        fwrite($handle, fread($filehandle, $chunksize));
    }
    fclose($filehandle);
    $filehandle = null;
}

function ytapi_write($handle, $request){
    fwrite($handle, $request);
    return $request;
}
```

Like so.

```
ytapi_write($handle, $start); //This writes the header.
ytapi_write_file($handle, $path, 8192); //This writes the file raw/binary.
ytapi_write($handle, $end); //This writes the final boundary.
```

Also, I use this for the header info:

```
$_header = array(
    'Host'=>'gdata.youtube.com',
    'Connection'=>'close',
    'User-Agent'=>'PHP',
    'Accept-encoding'=>'identity'
);
```

Any idea as to what I'm doing wrong? I can provide more information if needed. The file I am uploading is a little over 3MB, a file that is sitting on the server in question. I've verified the location is correct.

### UPDATE

Changed to uploads.gdata.youtube.com

Now I get this error message:

```
Host: uploads.gdata.youtube.com
Connection: close
User-Agent: PHP
Accept-encoding: identity
tcp://uploads.gdata.youtube.com:80HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
Server: HTTP Upload Server Built on Apr 8 2013 13:06:58 (1365451618)
X-GData-User-Country: US
Content-Type: application/vnd.google.gdata.error+xml
X-GUploader-UploadID: <SOME ID>
Date: Thu, 18 Apr 2013 19:42:14 GMT
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate
Content-Length: 228
Connection: close
```

Comment: Changed to uploads.gdata.youtube.com

Comment: I think there should be 'https'

Comment: Can't you use CURL from my example? You wont need to deal with 'Content-Length' and file chunks.

Comment: I'm trying to implement it now.

Comment: The server is sending back an XML-formatted entity. What error message does that XML actually say?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was mine implementation:

```
$data = '<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<entry xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:media="http://search.yahoo.com/mrss/" xmlns:yt="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007">
    <media:group>
        <media:title type="plain">' . $title . '</media:title>
        <media:description type="plain">' . trim($description) . '</media:description>
        <media:keywords>' . $tags . '</media:keywords>
        <media:category scheme="http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007/categories.cat">Music</media:category>
    </media:group>
</entry>';
$headers = array(
    'Authorization: GoogleLogin auth=' . $auth,
    'GData-Version: 2',
    'X-GData-Key: key=<KEY>',
    'Slug: ' . basename($videoPath)
);

$tmpfname = tempnam("/tmp", "youtube");
$handle = fopen($tmpfname, "w");
fwrite($handle, $data);
fclose($handle);

$post = array(
    'xml' => '@' . $tmpfname . ";type=application/atom+xml",
    'video' => '@' . $videoPath . ";type=video/mp4",
);
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "uploads.gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/default/uploads");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: What is the $auth variable? The validated token? Very glad to get help! :)

Comment: Yes. '<TOKEN IS HERE>'. I take it from 'https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin' request with 'Email' and 'Passwd'. Didn't deal with OAuth.

Comment: Ok, ran your example and didn't get an error. Did not show up in my youTube video list yet, so not sure if it worked or not. Here's hoping.

Comment: var_dump($content) after curl_close($ch);

Comment: Changed it to 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $auth. WORKED! finally, after a week of pain. I'll send you the oAuth code if you want it, it's pretty simple.